# How to deploy Firemonkey HD application for OSX running on VM?

Tags: macos, deployment, firemonkey

I have developed FireMonkey HD application for MAC OSX.I am running it on MAC virual machine using Platform Assistant and it runs well on MAC.Now I want to deploy it For MAC.I have give path to make output release by click on project -> options -> output directory but that release does not works on MAC.